# Multiple languages what to do with title tags alt tags etc

Tags: multilingual, language

The title says it all: Multiple languages what to do with title tags alt tags etc. I found a similar questions but the answer was not exactly what I was hoping for.

**Situation:**

1 WordPress installation (MultiSite, sub-dirctories). Every site has the name of the language (i.e. the English site is called 'English', German site 'German' etc) and I use a small PHP script to get the site name and call some variables like `lang="en"`. Now my static content like my logo, phone icon, mail icon etc have alt tag in English (that is the main language), but now I am wondering if this has to change depending on the language.

The content filled in WordPress like pictures will be uploaded separated because it is a multisite. I can change these in WordPress self, so it is pure the static images.

**TL;DR:** Do I have to have my static images have alt / title tags in the language of the content or is this not important (i.e. can my German site have English alt tags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt attributes are essentially to tell users what an image is about, so if you have the rest of your content localized, it would make sense to localize those too.